# Could not scrape some values from json file in python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, shopify

I would like scrape the data from json file, however I could not scrape the availability ("available" in json file) of the json value. The other values are scrapped successfully.

It shown blank on the column.

```
var availability= "" if i >= len(variants) else variants[i].get('available', '')
```

```
import asyncio
import os
import random
import time
import openpyxl
import aiohttp
from urllib import request

# path="C:/Users/pengoul/Downloads/dl" 
path = os.getcwd()
print(f"CWD is {path}")
path = os.path.join(path, "download")
if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

# picpath= os.makedirs('picture')
async def request():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url='https://hiutdenim.co.uk/products.json?limit=500') as resp:
            html = await resp.json()
            k = list()
            f = openpyxl.Workbook()
            sheet = f.active
            sheet.append(['Name', 'Barcode', 'Product Category', 'Image', 'Internal Reference', 'Sales Price','Product Tags'])

            products = []

            print("Saving to excel ...")
            for i in html['products']:
                title = i.get('title')
                id1 = i.get('id')
                product_type = i.get('product_type')
                images = [img.get('src', '') for img in i.get('images', [])]
                products.append((title, id1, product_type, images))
                variants = [var for var in i.get('variants')]
                for i in range(max(len(images), len(variants))):
                    imgsrc = "" if i >= len(images) else images[i]
                    varsku = "" if i >= len(variants) else variants[i].get('sku', '')
                    varprice = "" if i >= len(variants) else variants[i].get('price', '')
                    varavailability= "" if i >= len(variants) else variants[i].get('available', '')
                    sheet.append([title, "'" + str(id1), product_type, imgsrc, varsku, varprice, varavailability])
                f.save(f"result230102.xlsx")

 print("Downloading images ...")
            for product in products:
                title, id1, product_type, images = product
                for seq, imgurl in enumerate(images):
                    print(f"Downloading img for {id1} ({seq + 1}/{len(images)})")
                    request.urlretrieve(imgurl, os.path.join(path, f"{id1}-{seq + 1}.jpg"))

async def download(url):
    image = url[0]
    file_name = f'{url[1]}.jpg'
    print(f'picpath/{file_name}')
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        time.sleep(random.random())
        async with session.get(image) as resp:
            with open(path+ file_name, mode='wb') as f:
                f.write(await resp.content.read())

#     print(f'picpath/{file_name}')


async def main():
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
    tasks = []
    await request()
    # for url in urls:
    #     tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(download(url)))
    # await asyncio.wait(tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(os.getpid())
    t1 = time.time()
    urls = []
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  
    loop.run_until_complete(main())  
    t2 = time.time()
    print('total：', t2 - t1)
```

[image]

It shown blank on this column.

I would like to scrape the values of "available" from json.

[image]

Comment: From what I see, your code looks ok.  However, it isn't runnable as you present it, so I can't be sure just what you're doing.  You'll have better luck at getting a good answer if you can supply a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @CryptoFool 'Hi , I updated whole code, pls kindly check it, thanks.

Comment: Should the value of `varavailability` be set to `False` if the `get` call is empty, and an empty string if the `if` condition is met? If this difference is important, then it's best to map these two conditions to different values.

Comment: Hi @frederick-douglas-pearce , My expectation is i have to scrap the links of all pictures and availability. Therefore, some column of availability is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code in my debugger, putting a breakpoint at the line in question. This breakpoint is hit many times during execution.  In some cases, it produces a `True` value for `varavailability` as you're expecting.

At some point, this line ends up executing when the value of `i` is `1` and the length of `variants` is also `1`.  In this case, per the `if` condition `if i >= len(variants)`, the variable `varavailability` is set to `""`.  `i` is allowed to have a value of `1` because the length of `images` in this case is `5`.  In this case, your loop `for i in range(max(len(images), len(variants))):` will iterate over `i` == `0` to `i` == `4`.  For each `i` value greater than `0`, `varavailability` will be set to `""`.  I can't be sure if this is the case you're wondering about, but it makes good sense that it is.

UPDATE:

As to how to fix this, the question centers on how the contents of `variants` and `images` relate to each other and on what you are doing in your loop:

```
for i in range(max(len(images), len(variants))):
    imgsrc = "" if i >= len(images) else images[i]
    varsku = "" if i >= len(variants) else variants[i].get('sku', '')
    varprice = "" if i >= len(variants) else variants[i].get('price', '')
    varavailability= "" if i >= len(variants) else variants[i].get('available', '')
    sheet.append([title, "'" + str(id1), product_type, imgsrc, varsku, varprice, varavailability])
```

It seems that the code is iterating over a list of products, and each product has two lists associated with it, a list of images, and a list of variants. My guess is that the contents of these two lists are independent...that each value in `images` does not correspond to a particular entry in `variants`.

If what you want is a table of product variants, one possible solution is to associate all of the images for a particular product with each of the variations of that product, and then just iterate over each of the variants.  That could be something like this:

```
imgsrc = " ".join(images)
for variant in variants:
    varsku = variants.get('sku', '')
    varprice = variants.get('price', '')
    varavailability = variants.get('available', '')
    sheet.append([title, "'" + str(id1), product_type, imgsrc, varsku, varprice, varavailability])
```

Comment: so how can I fix this problem? should i put the code like this? 
varavailability= "" if i > len(variants) else variants[i].get('available', 'null')

Comment: Please clarify the output you expect and what you mean by "fix this problem"? What behavior do you want if `available` isn't present versus when the `if` clause is true, and why?

Comment: my expectation is extracts the values of availability , and i dun know why which step i missed? all columns of available is blank.

Comment: @pengoul - I added a section to my answer to address how you might fix your code.  I hope it helps.